# How to copy certain strings from txt file to Word doc using Python?

Tags: python, ms-word

I want to copy a word or string from txt file to word file at a certain block of table!

can someone guide me how to do it?

Best Regards,

Usman

Comment: This seems a bit broad. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Would you give an example of what it will do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is how to write a word (.docx) file. There is a library called [`docx`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Simply installed using pip:

```
pip install python-docx
```

Here is a short example that writes a docx file for you.

```
from docx import Document

document = Document()
document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)
p = document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some text')

document.save('demo.docx')
```

Here is a script that that will read a text file and add lines that match a condition to a word file. I would change the `matches_my_condition` function to your own needs.

```
from docx import Document

def matches_my_condition(line):
    """ Returns true or false if the given line should be added to the document """
    # Which will return true if the word cake appears in the line
    return 'cake' in line

# Prepare document
document = Document()

with open('my_text_file.txt', 'r') as textfile:
    for line in textfile.readlines():
        if matches_my_condition(line):
            document.add_paragraph(line)

document.save('my_cake_file.docx')
```